# Como intereferir na execução de uma função chamada por callback de eventListener Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

eu tenho uma aplicação web aqui que tem event listener de "mouseouver". A função callback chamada por ele fica sendo executada recursivamente através de uma setTimeOut():

```
/*........*/
   item.addEventListener("mouseover", changeBar, false)
/*........*/



function changeBar(event){

    const element = event.target
    const newBegining = element.offsetWidth+step
    if (newBegining < end){
        element.style.width = newBegining+"px"
        timeOutId = setTimeout(() => changeBar(event), 5)
    } 
 }
```

Só que eu queria parar de chamar recursivamente ela no caso de ocorrer um outro tipo de evento no elemento em questão: mouseout. (antes que o if dela dê false)

Só que claro, eu fiz um eventListener pro mouseout e ele chama sua callback, que mesmo que fosse essa mesma função acima, ela não interfere na execução já disparada pelo mouseover antes, e que ainda está executando recursivamente, correto?

Então, tem alguma forma de eu parar essa função recursiva chamada pelo mouseover, que não envolve colocar uma variável booleana global no if dela, e alterá-la no callback do mouseout (eu tentei isso, mas pro que eu quero fazer não dá certo, só funciona na primeira vez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso você pode utilizar a função [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) ela recebe o id do timeout e cancela a execução dele. O exemplo abaixo demonstra o funcionamento do clearTimeout.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('Timeout 1');
}, 1000);

var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('Timeout 2');
}, 1000);

// Para a execução do timeout 2
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

No seu caso já é guardado o id do timeout na variável `timeOutId`. É só utilizar ela no clearTimeout na função que trata evento `mouseout`.

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado algo do tipo. Vou testar do jeito que você disse amanhã de manhã. Eu volto pra marcar o certinho se der certo.